# Como resolver o erro "There is no default constructor in ..." em Java?

Tags: java, herança, construtor, classes-abstratas

Tenho uma classe abstrata chamada `Veiculo` que possui dois construtores:

```
public abstract class Veiculo {

    // Atributos ...

    public Veiculo(Marcas marca, int velocidade){...}

    public Veiculo(Marcas marca, int velocidade, Cores cor){...}

    // Métodos abstratos ...
}
```

Além dessa classe, possuo outra chamada `Carro`, que estende a classe abstrata `Veiculo` e implementa todos os métodos declarados como abstratos.

Porém a classe `Carro` não sobrescreve os construtores pois, eu desejo utilizar os construtores da classe herdada na classe `Carro` e em outras classes que eu criar e estenderem `Veiculo`.

```
Carro veiculo = new Carro(Marcas.FERRARI, 420, Cores.VERMELHO);
```

Abaixo está o código da classe:

```
public class Carro extends Veiculo {

    public String abrirJanela(){...}

    public String dirigir(){...}

    public String getMarca(){...}

    public String quebrar(){...}
}
```

O problema que está acontecendo, é que o Intellij IDEA me mostra a seguinte mensagem de erro na linha em que eu estendo a classe:

> There is no default constructor available in 'veiculo.Veiculo'

O que eu estou fazendo de errado no meu código?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O primeiro e principal erro é achar que existe herança de construtor. Não existe, você tem que criar os construtores de todas as classes, e aconselho fortemente fazer isso. Construtores são métodos estáticos, não é possível fazer herança, não faz sentido, e mccada tipo tem uma necessidade.

O que dá para fazer é no construtor da filha invocar o construtor da classe mãe de forma simplificada, algo assim:

```
public Carro(Marcas marca, int velocidade, Cores cor) {
    super(marca, velocidade, cor);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Super.java).

Mesmo que deseje não ter construtor algum é obrigatório ter pelo menos o construtor padrão que é o mínimo necessário para construir um objeto.

Um possível erro estaria na classe mãe. Toda classe deve ter pelo menos o construtor padrão, que é um construtor sem parâmetros, assim o objeto pode ser instanciado através deste construtor. Você normalmente não precisa criá-lo, o compilador cria para você. Exceto se você criar outros construtores com parâmetros, aí o *default constructor* não é criado, e como tem outros construtores ele costuma não ser necessário mesmo, em geral nem deveria existir porque existem construtores melhores.

Pode ser que você não queira criar esse construtor, é comum fazer sentido não tê-lo, e acho que é o ideal nesse caso, mesmo não sabendo muito sobre o problema. Tem uma pergunta que explica isso melhor: [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

O problema está ocorrendo porque a classe filha não tendo um construtor que chame o construtor da classe de forma especializada, mais ou menos como eu mostrei acima, a única forma que o compilador pode chamar o construtor da classe mãe por você é através do construtor padrão, que não existe e dá esse erro.

Não estou garantindo, mas tudo indica que deve criar os construtores de `Carro` e
o erro desaparece. Não garanto porque todo esse exemplo para ter problemas, mesmo resolvendo esse estará aprendendo OOP de forma errada.

Answer (score 0):

Após quebrar bastante a cabeça e pesquisar muito, descobri que o erro era causado porque o construtor da classe `Veiculo` era chamado implicitamente, sem a passagem de parâmetro.

Se o meu construtor não recebe parâmetro algum esse erro jamais aconteceria, porém o meu construtor recebe. O que eu deveria fazer, era criar os mesmos construtores para a classe `Carro` com os mesmos parâmetros e no corpo da função, utilizar o `super`. Exemplo:

```
public class Carro extends Veiculo{

    public Carro(Marcas marca, int velocidade){
        super(marca, velocidade);
    }

    public Carro(Marcas marca, int velocidade, Cores cor){
        super(marca, velocidade, cor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Para complementar a sua resposta, este comportamento está descrito no antepenúltimo parágrafo da [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). É um comportamento normal :)